# Laravel - Save HTML Dom-Parser response to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, dom

I have managed to get some HTML from a website using HTMLDomParser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/):

```
$html = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html('https://example.com/id=1');
```

This results in the following HTML:

```html
<p> ANDE 2, the Atmospheric Neutral Density Experiment 2, is a pair of microsatellites (Castor and Pollux) launched from Cape Canaveral on STS 127 on 15 July 2009 at 22:03 UT and deployed from the payload bay of the shuttle on 30 July 2009 at 17:22 UT.</p>
<p><strong>Launch Date:</strong> 2009-07-15<br/><strong>Launch Vehicle:</strong> Shuttle<br/><strong>Launch Site:</strong> Cape Canaveral, United States<br/></p>
```

What I want to attempt to do is to take this HTML and save it to a mySQL database. So, in the database I will have four columns:

- Description
- Launch Date
- Launch Vehicle
- Launch Site

The HTML layout will always stay the same. My other database contains the `id`'s for the URL's. I am able to replace the `id=1` with a variable, so I would be able to manage to save multiple webpage data.

The only thing I am worrying about if the `id` does not exist. Would it be possible just to skip that page if it cannot find the HTML it is looking for?

I have never done this before, so I am a bit overwhelmed by this. Would it even be possible to do this?

Basically, I just want to save data from a DomParser into my database.

**EDIT:** Since there has not been an answer, I think we need to tackle this systematically - first we should try creating the function that saves the data to the database.

**EDIT 2:** I was just thinking - maybe the function that needs to save the HTML can split the result from HTMLDomParser by tag ('strong', 'p', etc.) and create a variable for each column and then save it. I guess the question here first is how do you split the HTML?

**EDIT 3:** Since I did not receive any answers / suggestions, I am guessing it is very complex to implement this. I still have not managed to come up with anything that saves the HTML successfully to my database.

Comment: What do you mean by if id does not exist? if you have the DB with Id then only fetch the pages that matches theses id. Based on my understanding of simplehtmldom component, if you give it wrong URL and if the route does not exist then you will not get the valid HTML. Wouldn't that be sufficient for you to do what you want to do?

Comment: @Andy Let's say I have the id's 1, 2, 3 in my database. But the website does not have a page about id 2 for example, I would get a 404 error. You are correct in regards that I will only fetch pages that match the id. The only thing is that some `id`'s that I have in my database might not exist in website, so I want to see if it is possible to handle that.

Comment: In that case how about using GuzzleHttp to read the URL to check the status code ? If the status code is 200 then that's the valid page for fetching data otherwise do not read that URL ? Or you can use try/catch in your loop and when you get exception ...just ignore it and move on to next iteration?

Comment: @Andy - Yes I guess, that would work. I am currently using Guzzle to get some JSON files to my database. Maybe somehow we could intergrate Guzzle and HTMLDomParser to achieve the same for the HTML? Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

To check if the ID is valid to the site, I suggest a curl function, so if $url exists, try and get the data (try and catch), if there is an error with the data, catch it and return appropriate response or log it and move to next valid url.

You will have to format the data with a separate function inside the try.

Hope that helps as methodology goes, good luck. Peace